# Vitest Mock Factory Never Called

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, vitest

Here is my code:

```
import { it, describe, expect, vi, beforeEach } from 'vitest';
const ClientAuthenticator = require('../src/client-authenticator');
const { ssmClient, getParameterCommand } = require('../src/helpers/aws');

const ssmClientMock = vi.fn();
const getParameterCommandMock = vi.fn();

vi.mock('../src/helpers/aws', () => {
    return {
        ssmClient: ssmClientMock,
        getParameterCommand: getParameterCommandMock,
    };
});

describe('ClientAuthenticator.authenticator Tests', () => {
    it('Should set correct client name', async () => {
        // Arrange
        console.log(ssmClient); // This logs real implementation not a mock.
        const clientId = 'clientId';
        const clientSecret = 'clientSecret';
        ... rest of the test ...
```

See that line that says `console.log(ssmClient)`? this one prints real implementation not the mock though it should return `ssmClientMock` (this happens also in the production code - it sees the real implementation not the mock.) What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Vitest works with ES6 modules. It has no effect if you're using `require`. More details are given here: https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-mock